# Error within Where statement in LINQ

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

For some reason in my where it says that "firstname" does not exist in the Opportunity Entity. But it is set for the SystemUser Entity. Any idea why it is getting confused? Thanks!

```
            var linqQuery = (from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
                             join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("account") on ((EntityReference)r["accountid"]).Id equals c["accountid"]
                             join u in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("systemuser") on ((EntityReference)r["ownerid"]).Id equals u["systemuserid"]
                             where r["new_leadstatus"].Equals("100000004") && u["lastname"].Equals(rsmLastName) && u["firstname"].Equals(rsmFirstName)
                             select new
                             {
                                 AccountId = !r.Contains("accountid") ? string.Empty : r["accountid"],
                                 Account = !r.Contains("name") ? string.Empty : r["name"]
                             });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you put each `where` clause in its own line [per Microsoft guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328328.aspx#bkmk_operators).

> The **where** clause applies a filter to the results, often using a
>   Boolean expression. The filter specifies which elements to exclude
>   from the source sequence. Each **where** clause can only contain
>   conditions against a single entity type. A composite condition
>   involving multiple entities is not valid. Instead, each entity should
>   be filtered in separate **where** clauses.

```cs
var linqQuery = from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
                join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("account") on ((EntityReference)r["accountid"]).Id equals c["accountid"]
                join u in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("systemuser") on ((EntityReference)r["ownerid"]).Id equals u["systemuserid"]
                where r["new_leadstatus"].Equals("100000004")
                where u["lastname"].Equals(rsmLastName) && u["firstname"].Equals(rsmFirstName)
                select new
                {
                    AccountId = !r.Contains("accountid") ? string.Empty : r["accountid"],
                    Account = !r.Contains("name") ? string.Empty : r["name"]
                };
```

Comment: Didn't know you could have two where statements. worked like charm, thanks!

Comment: Learn something new everyday. Thanks @Peter

Comment: Just spent a couple hours banging my head against the wall over this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You define your reference to the Opportunity entity as 'r' but are trying to read firstname from 'u'

```
from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")

u["firstname"]
```

Change the end of your where to

```
r["firstname"].Equals(rsmFirstName)
```

Comment: but i want to check the firstname from systemuser not opportunity and lnew_leadstatus from opportunity.