# How to query (using LINQ) FormattedValues in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using LINQ to retrieve Account type entities from Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online. I am unable to filter the list for a particular formatted value. I have the correct value, but am receiving zero records. 
I'm creating my connection like this:

```
var connection = new CrmConnection("CRMOnline");
connection.ProxyTypesEnabled = true;
CrmOrganizationServiceContext _context = new CrmOrganizationServiceContext(connection);
```

I've tried:

```
List<Account> items = _context.CreateQuery<Account>()
                              .Where( c => ((OptionSetValue)c["new_accreditationstatus"]).Equals(7))
                              .ToList();
```

and

```
List<Account> items = _context.CreateQuery<Account>()
                              .Where( c => c.GetFormattedAttributeValue("new_accreditationstatus") == "7"
                              .ToList();
```

and

```
List<Account> items = _context.CreateQuery<Account>()
                              .Where( c => c["new_accreditationstatus"] == "7"
                              .ToList();
```

The last on throws a System.Format exception.

Filters on normal properties, i.e. `.Where(c => c.AccountNumber.StartsWith("2010"))` work perfectly fine.

Comment: If you're enabling proxy types, why is the Account.new_accreditationstatus have to be accessed by string key value?  Doesn't it have a property accessor created for it?

Comment: What type of field is new_accreditationstatus?

Comment: @Daryl it does not. It's only available in the attributed collection. I did not set up the database, nor do I have access except via the web service.

Comment: @glosrob: `new_accreditationstatus` looks to be of type `OptionSetValue`, based on the cast above.

Comment: @glosrob It's a string value, but I believe it's used in a select list. So the value is a number, but has a string formatted value. I know both values, so I can query by either.

Comment: @SteveMallory you should be able to recreate your early bound objects using the CrmSdkUtil.  When you do that, it'll create a new early bound C# file that will contain an Account.new_accreditationstatus property.  The only thing it uses are the web services to create the file.

Comment: @Daryl thanks. I followed up with Peter's comment in one of the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only get access to the `_____Set` entities when generating the early-bound CRM file (look into `crmsvcutil.exe`/`Xrm.cs` online) and creating an early-bound derivative of `CrmOrganizationServiceContext` (commonly called `XrmServiceContext`). You can see the available constructors in the early-bound file.

So if you know the (int) value of the `OptionSetValue` in advance (7, in this case), you can just use this value as one of the arguments in the `Where` clause, as you've stated elsewhere:

```cs
.Where( c => c.new_AccreditationStatus.Value == 7)
```

Comment: For future reference: The utility comes with the SDK. The help is at [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT (try this):

```
var list = _context.AccountSet.Where(c => 
                     c.FormattedValues["new_accreditationstatus"] == "7").ToList();
```

Comment: That raised another exception: `System.NotSupportedException` - Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method

Comment: @EkoosstikMartin Strangely enough, I do not have that (or any) collection built in to the context object. I am extremely new to Dynamics CRM Online, so I may be missing an obvious setting.

Comment: @SteveMallory: You can only get access to the `_____Set` entities when generating the early-bound CRM file (look into `crmsvcutil.exe`/`Xrm.cs` online) and creating an early-bound derivative of `CrmOrganizationServiceContext` (commonly called `XrmServiceContext`). You can see the available constructors in the early-bound file.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin: Out of curiosity, does this actually work for you? I always get the same message that Steve gets in his first comment.

Comment: @PeterMajeed well that little utility is quite handy! And it was the key. I am now able to use a linq predicate without jumping through any hoops. i.e. `.Where( c => c.new_AccreditationStatus.Value == 7)`. I would hate for your answer to go to waste, since it may help someone else in the future. Could you add another answer (basically reiterating your comment), and then I'll accept that.

Comment: @SteveMallory: Long, pointless answers - the story of my StackOverflow life. :-) I've added an another answer per your request.

Comment: @PeterMajeed: no it doesn't work in this case, I was lazy and missed he wasn't using a design time service reference to generate his servicecontext. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Another great question, but unfortunately, I think this will represent another [failure/"limitation" of the Linq provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820663/error-within-where-statement-in-linq/10821137#10821137), which doesn't mention anything about `FormattedValues` as one of the permitted uses of the `Where` clause, though it is permitted as an item in the `Select` clause.

The actual values for `OptionSetValue`s are stored in the `StringMap` entity, and incidentally enough, you *can* access the `StringMap` entity via Linq. An example is as follows.

```cs
// This query gets one permissible value for this entity and field.
var actualValue = _context.CreateQuery("stringmap")
    .Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue<string>("attributename") == "new_accreditationstatus")
    .Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue<int>("value") == "7")
    .Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue<int>("objecttypecode") == Account.EntityTypeCode)
    .Select(x => x.GetAttributeValue<string>("value"))
    .Single();
```

However, trying to build on this with a subquery and a version of your original query, as in the below, results in an exception, also below.

```
var actualValues = _context.CreateQuery("stringmap")
    .Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue<string>("attributename") == "new_accreditationstatus")
    .Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue<int>("objecttypecode") == Xrm.Account.EntityTypeCode);

// This (modified) query uses the StringMap values from the previous query in
// a subquery, linking to the int (attributevalue) value that
// new_accreditationstatus represents.
List<Account> items = _context.CreateQuery<Account>()
    .Where(c => actualValues
        .Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue<int>("attributevalue") == c.new_accreditationstatus.Value)
        .Select(x => x.GetAttributeValue<string>("attributevalue"))
        .Single() == "7")
    .ToList();
```

...throws an exception.

> > Privilege Type Read not defined on entity 'StringMap'.

Which is of course frustrating, because somehow, Linq allows you to query the string map in the first query.

So you'll have to first query the `StringMap` entity for the `AttributeValue` that corresponds to "7", then use that value in a *new* query that references that value as follows:

```
var actualValue = _context.CreateQuery("stringmap")
    .Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue<string>("attributename") == "new_accreditationstatus")
    .Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue<int>("value") == "7")
    .Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue<int>("objecttypecode") == Account.EntityTypeCode)
    .Select(x => x.GetAttributeValue<string>("attributevalue"))
    .Single();

List<Account> items = _context.CreateQuery<Account>()
    .Where(c => c.new_accreditationstatus = new OptionSetValue(actualValue)
    .ToList();
```

If I can ever find a way to do all of this in one query, I will definitely edit and repost.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [the crmsvcutil extension that will generate enumerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547384.aspx) for optionsets?