# Basic Linq join with filter on both tables - CRM 2011

Tags: vb.net, linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error within Where statement in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820663/error-within-where-statement-in-linq)

I need to get a list of all quotes that have been changed since a certain DateTime ( for export reasons ).

The catch is of course that if a quote detail changes, the quote should also be exported even if the the quote itself hasn't changed.

I would solve this very easily in *T-SQL* as :

```
Select q.QuoteNumber from quote q inner join quotedetails qd on q.quoteid = qs.quoteid
where ((q.lastmodified > ?1) or (qd.lastmodified > ?1)) and (qd.SomeField = 'OK')
```

However, with Linq to CRM 2011, I stumble upon a restriction.

```
var quotelist = from q in xrm.quoteSet
join qd in xrm.quoteDetailSet
on q.QuoteId equals qd.QuoteId.Id
where (q.lastmodified > ?1 | qd.lastmodified > ?1) & qd.Somefield == "OK"

select q.QuoteNumber
```

It says that the Quote entity has no attribute SomeField.

Just FYI, this is just an example query to show the problem. I cannot switch Quote and QuoteDetail in my real life query.

What is the cleanest way to convert my *T-SQL* query (as is) to a *Linq* query for *CRM 2011*?

Comment: Also, is this an on-premise or online deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [the MSDN samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509017.aspx#JoinUsingEntityFields)?  I'm confused why you are getting the error "no attribute" on the Quote entity when your prefix is referencing QouteDetail (**qd**.Somefield)

The only other thing that looks suspicious is your single & and | in the where clause.  I believe you should have those doubled up: && and ||

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you created your early bound objects with the SomeField attribute, and then someone removed the field?